# Where should the API reside?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, microservices

I have a microservice(`opsApiServ`) which hosts API to do operations(ops).

1. /ops - POST, GET
2. /ops-item - GET

`ops-item` is just a single unit of operation, and `ops` is collection of operations (ops-item).
Since, there are payload and getaway timeout limits, we just let clients do only 5k ops in one request.

Now, there are some users which want to do much more than that. So, to serve their demands, I have come up with an offline procedure.

Client can drop a file having list of `ops-item` details, and my `batch-application` will be doing offline work by logically spliting `ops-file`. We will also have a `ops-milestone` which is a logical split-group of `ops-item`. This work is done by acting just as a client of `opsApiServ` by consuming `ops` and `ops-item`.

So, the hierarchy goes like this:

`ops-file` <-- `ops-milestone` <-- `ops` <-- `ops-item`

now, there is a need to treat `ops-file` and `ops-milestone` as a REST-Resource.

**Question:**

- Where should the new API for `/ops-file` and `/ops-milestone` live considering REST and Microservices standpoint ? Should they be in separate microservice or `opsApiServ` ?
- I really get confused how and where to draw the boundary. Is there a golden rule?

**Any pointers / links would be fine**

Comment: Without knowing more, I would recommend just putting those endpoints in your existing microservice.  It appears all the concepts are closely related, so it would fit the logical design of your microservice.  If the concepts were completely different, and the data was unrelated I would argue for a separate microservice.  It all boils down to your design.

Comment: Hi @BerinLoritsch, thank you for the view. I would like to understand so far `batch-application` is acting as just a client of microservice. So should not we treat that as a different system, and create a new microservice. I really get confused how and where to draw the boundary.

Comment: You can play around with aggregates to help you understand boundaries, though that opens a whole new can of worms for some developers.  There's no right or wrong way to do this.  **Rule of thumb:** these boundaries are often similar to those of a department or job function.

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey, you mentioned "though that opens a whole new can of worms for some developers.". can you please elaborate?

Comment: @hemal7735, boundaries are not set in stone.  If you have two equal routes you can go, think through the options and if there still isn't a winner, just choose one.  It's more important to move forward than to get everything "perfect".  If it doesn't feel right after a while it's still early enough you can change where you draw the boundary, and that's OK.